# should we delete the build directories created in LFS for installing binutils-2.20?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, binutils, linux-from-scratch

I am in the part ( http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.6/chapter05/binutils-pass2.html)
                 ( http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.6/chapter05/binutils-pass1.html)

they ask me to build binutils again? i dont understand should we delete the binutils-build directory we used in the begining and create a new one for this build??? and what is pass 1 and pass 2? i am confused :/

please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rush through this, I am NOT an lfs user (let alone an expert), and in 2 minutes of reading I found

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.6/chapter05/generalinstructions.html

> Important After installing each
>   package, delete its source and build
>   directories, unless specifically
>   instructed otherwise. Deleting the
>   sources prevents mis-configuration
>   when the same package is reinstalled
>   later.

Pass1 builds a preliminary set of tools that work, Pass2 is building a set of tools that are optimized for your environment. Again, reread everything in chap5. Some experience with compilers is assumed.

Finally, from a comment by @yasouser on one of your previous questions,

> See ... LFS Mailing Lists (linuxfromscratch.org/mail.html)

IHTH